# Dynamic assignment does not really initialize the hashtable

Tags: c, hashtable

Dynamic assignment does not really initialize the hashtable

I have the following code and I need to insert members into chain-> data but it's not really from an end I have 0x01214ad0 (key = 0, chain = 0x0z294d0

hashtable.h

```
struct HashTableElement
{
    int key;
    LinkedList* chain;
};

typedef struct HashTable HashTable;

struct HashTable
{
    HashTableElement* hashTable;
    int hashFunction;
    int tableSize;
    int cellsTaken;
    int numOfElements;
};
```

linked list.h

```
typedef struct LinkedList LinkedList;

struct LinkedList {
    char* data;
    LinkedList* next;

};
```

hash table.c

```
HashTable* initTable(int tableSize, int hashFunction) {
    HashTable* table = (HashTable*)malloc(sizeof(HashTable));
    table->tableSize = tableSize;
    table->hashFunction = hashFunction;
    if (table == NULL || tableSize < 1)
    {
        printf("EROR with malloc in initTable.");
        exit(1);
    }
    table->hashTable = malloc(sizeof(HashTableElement) * tableSize);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < hashFunction; i++) {
        table->hashTable[i].key = NULL;
        table->hashTable[i].chain = NULL;
    }
    return table;
}
int insert(HashTable* ht, char* str)
{
    HashTable* temp;
    int h = hash(str, ht);
    int i = 0;
    while (ht->hashTable[h].key == 0) {       
        ht->hashTable->chain = (LinkedList*)malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));
        ht->hashTable->chain[0].data = *str;
    }  
    return 0;
}
```

this line need to insert "value" of str but its not...
ht->hashTable->chain[0].data = *str;

the warnings of vs:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning C4047   'function': 'char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'char'   workhome4   C:\Users\yovel\source\repos\workhome4\workhome4\HashTable.c 58  
Warning C4024   'asciiStringHashFunction': different types for formal and actual parameter 1    workhome4   C:\Users\yovel\source\repos\workhome4\workhome4\HashTable.c 58  
Warning C4047   '=': 'char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'char'  workhome4   C:\Users\yovel\source\repos\workhome4\workhome4\HashTable.c 81  
Warning C4101   'temp': unreferenced local variable workhome4   C:\Users\yovel\source\repos\workhome4\workhome4\HashTable.c 76  
Warning C4474   'printf' : too many arguments passed for format string  workhome4   C:\Users\yovel\source\repos\workhome4\workhome4\HashTable.c 88  
Message     placeholders and their parameters expect 0 variadic arguments, but 1 were provided  workhome4   C:\Users\yovel\source\repos\workhome4\workhome4\HashTable.c 88
```

Comment: You have `struct LinkedList { char* data; ... };` so you cannot write `*str` (a char) to that field. Something like `strcpy` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Can you write to me?

Comment: Looking at the `struct HashTable` there isn't any type `HashTableElement`. There is, however, a `struct HashTableElement`. Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as text, the shortest *complete* code that shows what you have tried.

Comment: This is the shortest unfortunately

Comment: Please enable compiler warnings. Besides kirjosieppo's comment, `table->hashTable[i].key = NULL;` is incorrect (it's an integer type).

Comment: It isn't the shortest possible. I was trying to paste the sections posted into a single source file, to check compiler warnings/errors. We should not have to do that - it's your job. May I suggest you take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: this is not the problem i enter into while

Comment: A [mcve] would be one file and it would have a `main` function, so people helping you can compile it and run it without unnecessary hurdles.  And in case it's not obvious, you should say the expected output you want to get, and the actual output.  Use copy and paste to avoid typos.  If you really work hard to make a *minimal* example, you'll often solve the problem on your own because your code will become so simple that the problem will be obvious.

Comment: Ok I appreciate how you do what you asked?

Comment: Re the edit: the compiler is telling you what is wrong. It is pointless running the code until you have fixed them. About my first comment - this can't be compiled with a C compiler. What compiler are you using?

Comment: visual studio 2019

Comment: The `while` loop in `insert()` is an infinite loop. Why do you need a loop at all?

Comment: You may find [Coding up a Hash Table](http://www.sparknotes.com/cs/searching/hashtables/section3.rhtml) and [Hash tables - eternally confuzzled](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/datastructures/jsw_tut_hashtable.aspx) useful. Your has table should be an array of pointers to nodes that are the nodes of the linked list. The hashtable type and linked list type are not separate. When you fill an element in your table, you handle any collision resulting in storing to the same element by chaining from the existing element. That's how collisions are handled. Don't ignore load-factor either.

Comment: Your struct `HashTable` is simply a container that keeps track what the statistics of the hashtable are and allows you to allocate and use multiple hashtables. The hashtable itself is the array of pointers to list nodes. [Hashtable of Strings - Example](https://pastebin.com/tgmYEJc9)